# Shell Script Won't Run From Java Program

Tags: java, shell, process

There are two things to note right off the bat....

1. The shell script runs fine manually
2. A simple shell script (echo hello) that I wrote runs fine through java

So I have a shell script that I'm attempting to run through a Java process.

```
File sqlF = new File("path to deploy script");

Process proc = rt.exec(sqlF + "/deploy.sh");
proc.waitFor();

System.out.println(proc.exitValue());
```

When I run this code I get an ambiguous return value of "1".

Here's the shell script (because I imagine the issue may stem from here):

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u XXXX -h XXXXX < XXXXX.sql
mysql -u XXXX -h XXXXX database < DEPLOY-HELPER.sql
```

Any ideas as to why this would not execute properly from Java?

Comment: turn on `set -vx` in your shell script and redirect stderr and stdout to a file so you can see what is going on. First guess is that you need to set your path to mysql. For a quick test, replace `mysql` with  `/full/path/to/mysql`. good luck.

Comment: are you running it on linux? also, invoking a process within java, it might not setup the path or import the variables from system properly.

Comment: @gigadot Yes, it's on Linux. And I'll give that a try shelter! Thanks.

Comment: I read the articles about using Java Process to run script may cuase problem since you may not pipe stdout, stderr, stdin properly. They recommend to use Apache Exec library and I found that it is easy to run external process as it handles the input and output streams for you.

Comment: It looks like @shelter is on the right path. After getting a hold of my stderr it showed that it doesn't know where my XXXX.sql is in line 2.

Comment: Turns out I just had to point specifically to my ".sql" files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a shell script you must explicitly invoke the shell and pass it the name of the script as an argument, as in

```
bash /path/to/script/deploy.sh
```

Neither `Runtime.exec()` nor `ProcessBuilder` know how to execute shell scripts themselves, they only know how to execute binary executables.